# What structured text format is that?

Tags: text, format

I am getting a string formatted as follows:

```
a:2:
{
 i:0;
 a:0:{}s:2:"o1";
 a:14:
 {
    s:8:"duration";
    i:299;
    s:12:"content_hash";
    s:32:"af1e3e5707da79c2et96d8280db6343e";
    s:12:"content_type";
    s:9:"video/mp4";
    s:9:"extension";
    s:3:"mp4";
    s:5:"width";
    i:1280;
    s:6:"height";
    i:720;
    s:6:"aspect";
    d:1.7800000000000000266453525910037569701671600341796875;
    s:15:"is_video_bucket";
    i:1;
    s:8:"revision";
    i:0;
```

This comes from Tumblr's API.
it's all made of chunks that have a letter to identify the type, followed by the size:

```
s:8:"duration";
i:299;
```

is really string (8 bytes) : "duration"; integer 299

but I'm not familiar with that structure; is it common?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found, it's UBJSON; I have never heard of it before

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UBJSON